# Replicate sumif formula in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, sumifs

I am performing a [sumifs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) operation in Excel and would need to replicate the same in Python.

Column 'E' in the below screenshot is my end requirement.
For example, In AMS Territory: Product 1 Sales is 100K however upon adjustment it changes to 116,667. This is done in the following way:

```
AMS Territory:

((Sales of Product 1 in AMS)/(sales of product1 + product2 + product3 + product4 in AMS)) * (Sales of 'All' Product in AMS)

i.e., 

(100K/600K)*700K = 116,667

APAC Territory:

((Sales of Product 1 in APAC)/(sales of product1 + product2 + product3 + product4 in APAC)) * (Sales of 'All' Product in APAC

i.e., 

(200K/1000K)*1200K = 240,000
```

[image]

Comment: please add some sample data with your expected output see [mcve] and [ask] pictures are not acceptable formats on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please include your data as code and not as screenshots. Also include the code you have tried (not pseudocode) and the expected output.

Comment: p.s you can copy directly from excel paste the data in, click `format as code` and we can paste that directly into our IDEs to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need with `groupby`:

```
#sort by territory and product
df = df.sort_values(["Territory", "Product"])

#compute total product sales (excluding All)
product_sales = df.groupby(["Territory", df["Product"]!="All"])["Sales"].transform("sum")

#get all sales per territory
all_sales = df["Sales"].where(df["Product"]=="All").ffill()

#compute adjusted sales
df["Adjusted Sales"] = df["Sales"].where(df["Product"]=="All", df["Sales"].div(product_sales).mul(all_sales))

>>> df

  Region Territory    Product    Sales  Adjusted Sales
0   East       AMS        All   700000    7.000000e+05
1   East       AMS  Product 1   100000    1.166667e+05
2   East       AMS  Product 2   200000    2.333333e+05
3   East       AMS  Product 3   150000    1.750000e+05
4   East       AMS  Product 4   150000    1.750000e+05
5   East      APAC        All  1200000    1.200000e+06
6   East      APAC  Product 1   200000    2.400000e+05
7   East      APAC  Product 2   300000    3.600000e+05
8   East      APAC  Product 3   250000    3.000000e+05
9   East      APAC  Product 4   250000    3.000000e+05
```